# Employees and managers in the same Project? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I did some digging and couldn't arrange it in my mind... My problem is finding employees and managers which are in the same project? I have 2 tables that they are Employee and Project. And they like;

```
   *Employee*               
   ----------               
   employee_id (PK)          
   name
   manager_id (FK)   ref employee_id in same table which is employee_id.
   usertype    

   *Project*
   ----------
   project_id(PK)
   project_name
   employee_id(FK)   ref employee_id in emplyee table
   manager_id(FK)    ref employee_id in emplyee table
```

Let me more specific. Project must have 1 manager and several employees. How can I write in query? usertype column specifies this employee MANAGER OR USER(normal employee).

Query run example:

```
       ______    ______________    ____________
       |name|    |manager_name|   |project_name|  
        John         Susan       CalendarIphone
        Mike         Susan       CalendarIphone
        Joe         Patrick        AndoridApp
        Megan        Susan        CalendarIphone
        Melek       Patrick        AndoridApp
```

AS you can see Mike can work in more than one project and can have more than one manager. But managers must own only 1 project. So how should I do that for getting this? Thank in advance.

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have an project which has dropdown list. I picked a Project here and it shows me a table according to this project and list me Manager of that Project, Employees in that project. I asked project name for just create one more column you can ignore it. I just want to see Manager of it and employees in it.

EDIT 2-----------------------------------------------------------

Project ID = 2 for example and in this project we have 1 manager and employees.

```
   |name|    |manager_name|    
    John         Susan      
    Mike         Susan       
    Joe          Susan       
    Megan        Susan       
    Melek        Susan
```

Comment: If Mike's manager varies from project to project, then it has no place in the `employee` table (nor the `project` table). It should be in the `project_employee` table

Comment: Which I dont understand manager is also an employee? Should manager_id refers employee_id?

Answer (score 4):

your schema is not good. It should be something like:

```
   Employee*               
   ----------               
   employee_id (PK)          
   name
   manager_id (FK)   ref employee_id in employee table

   *Project*
   ----------
   project_id(PK)
   project_name
   manager_id(FK)    ref employee_id in employee table

   *Project_Employee*
   ----------
   project_id(FK)  ref project_id in project table
   employee_id(FK) ref employee_id in employee table
```

then you can do:

```
   select
       e.name as name,
       em.name as manager_name
       p.project_name
       pm.name as project_manager_name
   from Employee as e
       left outer join Employee as em on em.employee_id = e.manager_id
       left outer join Project_Employee as pe on pe.employee_id = e.employee_id
       left outer join Project as p on p.project_id = pe.project_id
       left outer join Employee as pm on pm.employee_id = p.manager_id
```

but as for each employee there could be more than one project, employee could duplicate in this query

**update**

```
 select
     e.name, u.is_manager
 from (
     select employee_id, 0 as is_manager from Project_Employee as pe where pe.idproject_id= <project id>
     union all
     select manager_id, 1 as is_manager from Project as p where p.project_id= <project id>
 ) as u
     inner join Employee as e on e.employee_id = u.employee_id
 order by u.is_manager desc
```

**update 2**

```
select
    e.name as employee_name,
    pm.name as manager_name
from Project_Employee as pe
    left outer join Employee as e on e.employee_id = pe.employee_id
    left outer join Project as p on p.project_id = pe.project_id
    left outer join Employee as pm on pm.employee_id = p.manager_id
where pe.project_id = <project id>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... What you suggest avoiding duplcate ?

Comment: in you question there's duplicate for Mark. You could use group_concat to get all projects for employe to comma separated string, for example, I don't know what're your goals.

Comment: I see your point. Please take a look to my edit. Thank in advance

Comment: check updated query. I still don't get your exact requirements, my query will return you a list of employees and bit attribute is_manager

Comment: thanks for your answer it helps. Let me ask you one more time :) I want to get Manager name and employees name in same project. But manager can not have more than 1 project. Employees can work on more than 1 project. When i run the query it should return in my last update :) see answer pls

Comment: It says p.employee_id is unknown column... I did exactly as your tables. I altered all table just like yours. Your project table has no employee_id column

Comment: the `employee.manager_id` field (+FK) is redundant IMHO. A person does not have a manager, (s)he is managed by the managers of the project(s) that (s)he works for.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't know that for sure, so it's up to OP

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.name AS name,
       m.name AS manager_name,
       project_name
FROM Project p
    JOIN Employee e ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
    JOIN Employee m ON m.employee_id = p.manager_id
```

Since each project row has the employee, and the manager, it's as simple as going to the `Employee` table on two different keys to get the employee's name as well as the manager's name. Then, it's natural to base the query off Project because that's the information you're gathering, so you can just pickup the `project_name` from there.